# InitializationException: Firebase app creation failed

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Extensions;

public class ManageLoginAndRegistration : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text loginTitle, registrationTitle;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject loginForm;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject registrationForm;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _login;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _registration;

    [SerializeField]
    private InputField loginEmail, regEmail, loginPassword, regPassword;

    public void GoToRegistrationPage()
    {
        loginForm.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        registrationForm.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        registrationTitle.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        loginTitle.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        _login.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        _registration.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void GoToLoginPage()
    {
        loginForm.SetActive(true);
        registrationForm.SetActive(false);
        registrationTitle.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        loginTitle.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _login.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _registration.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not reslove all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    void OnClickSignIn()
    {

    }
    public void OnClickSignUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("Signup clicked");
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(regEmail.text, regPassword.text).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signup Canceled");
                return;
            }

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signup Failed");
                return;
            }
            Debug.Log("Signup Successful");
            AuthResult authResult = task.Result;
            FirebaseUser newUser = authResult.User;

            Debug.LogFormat("User created successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting

> InitializationException:  Firebase app creation failed.
> Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/macos_unity/x86_64/app/swig/Firebase.App_fixed.cs:2598

this error when I am trying to signup in unity project with firebase authentication. Can any one solve this error?